# Function not working properly when called by a method : Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So when I am calling the list directory code below directly then it's working fine. But when I am calling main.py which uses app class from gui which calls the  list directory function, It prints "yoo" but prints an empty list instead of list of directories. I am stuck and can't figure out why that's happening. Any ideas?

Outputs:

When list directory called directly :

```
["/home/shubham/Desktop/movies/djangounchained.mkv"] 

"yoo"
```

When called by main.py with same argument:

```
[]

"yoo"
```

Here is my main script

```
from gui import app                                                                                                                            
from list_directory import display_files                                                                                                       
import tkinter as tk                                                                                                                           

root = tk.Tk()                                                                                                                                 
directory = input("Enter directory name:")                                                                                                     
root.geometry("400x300")                                                                                                                       
widgets_creator = app(root)                                                                                                                    
name = "get list"                                                                                                                              
directory_button = widgets_creator.create_button(name,function=display_files,path=directory)                                                   
root.mainloop()
```

Here is my gui script

```
import tkinter as tk                                                                                                                           

class app(tk.Frame):                                                                                                                           
    def __init__(self,master):                                                                                                                 
       super(app,self).__init__(master=master)                                                                                                 
       self.master = master                                                                                                                    
       self.init_window()                                                                                                                      

    def init_window(self):                                                                                                                     

        # changing the title of our master widget                                                                                              
        self.master.title("GUI")                                                                                                               

        # allowing the widget to take the full space of the root window                                                                        
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)                                                                                                      

        # creating a button instance                                                                                                           
        quitButton = tk.Button(self, text="Quit")                                                                                              

        # placing the button on my window                                                                                                      
        quitButton.place(x=0, y=0)                                                                                                             


    def create_button(self,button_name,function,path):                                                                                         
        button = tk.Button(self.master,text=button_name,command=lambda: function(path))                                                        
        button.place(x=200,y=5)                                                                                                                
        return button
```

Here is my list_directory code:

```
import glob                                                                                                                                    
def display_files(path):                                                                                                                       
    x = glob.glob(path)                                                                                                                        
    print(x)                                                                                                                                   
    print("yoo")                                                                                                                               

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                     
     display_files("/home/shubham/Desktop/movies/*")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have found your problem. The code works fine, the problem is your argument. For example, if I enter `'/Users/rudy/Desktop/*'` when the input prompt comes up, I have the same result as you.

However, when I enter `/Users/rudy/Desktop/*` (without quotes), everything works fine. `input()` already saves the input as a string, so you don't need to add additional quotes.

Comment: Woah. Worked. Hail Rudolf ;).